# How to import .bak file into SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, migration, backup, database-restore

I have a file with a `.bak` extension.

How can I import this data into a database in SQL Server?

Any command to import data?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is such [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) -

```
RESTORE DATABASE myDatabase
FROM  DISK = N'E:\Backups\myDatabase.bak;'
```

But you can check [restoring using SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-database-backup-using-ssms?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Yes, man. You just set database name and the location of your `bak` file.

Comment: I have tried above command but i am getting below error: 

mysql> RESTORE DATABASE user \
    -> FROM DISK = N'/home/pradeep/AdventureWorks2012.bak;'
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RESTORE DATABASE user 
FROM DISK = N'/home/pradeep/AdventureWorks2012.bak;'' at line 1
mysql>

Comment: mysql version : mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper